# How to store the current zoomed image in PyQt5 matplotlib application

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am using this application: [OrthoViewLite](https://github.com/Axel-Erfurt/OrthoViewLite/blob/main/OrthoViewLite.py).

I have put `print` commands throughout the code in order to see in which part the code is related to the zoom button when I zoom the image. It didn't help. Also, when I press the "store current (zoomed) image button" I do not see any changes in any numbered `print` commands ( I use them like this: `print("1")`, `print("2")`, ... `print("250")`).

So, my question is: which is the part of the code that stores the **current zoomed image**?

Comment: I don't understand. In the title you ask how to store a zoomed image, but in the question body you ask where is the function that does it. What is it that you want to know? Note that if you really want to know where is the code that does that, then the question is off topic: StackOverflow is a place for specific programming questions, and asking people to go through somebody else's code to find what you need is clearly not that kind of question. Go through the code, **study** it, read the documentation of the classes and functions it uses and their relative sources.

Comment: I need to put a button to store the current zoomed photo. So, as far as I push the button to store it with a predefined name: `zoomed_photo.jpg`.

Comment: I don't want the user to click the "store" button and insert via the keyboard a filename. I need to just press the "store" button (or a new "store" button) and the current image to be stored with a predefined name....

Comment: Then, as said, go through the code. The function is certainly in the imported matplotlib module, so you have to read it and *study* it. Putting a bunch of `print()` statements randomly won't help you here, as it's obvious that in the code you posted there's no such reference to that specific function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that saves the current image is part of the matplotlib [NavigationToolbar2QT class](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c57c8781a7b9d8e5e9ece7c4cb8acee3b692f7f2/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py#L611). The toolbar buttons for this class are defined in the `toolitems` attribute which is inherited from the [NavigationToolbar2 class](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c57c8781a7b9d8e5e9ece7c4cb8acee3b692f7f2/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2874). These definitions create a "Save" button which calls the toolbar's [save_figure()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c57c8781a7b9d8e5e9ece7c4cb8acee3b692f7f2/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py#L754) method when clicked. This method generates a default filepath for the file-dialog, and calls [matplotlib.pyplot.savefig](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) to save the image to disk.

So, to create your own image-save button, all you really need is `savefig`. The OrthoViewLite code can therefore be quite easily adapted like this:

```
class OrthoView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        self.tb.addAction(go_home_btn)
        
        # add a new tool bar button
        my_save_btn = QAction("My Save", self, triggered=self.mySave)
        my_save_btn.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-save"))
        self.tb.addAction(my_save_btn)
        ...
    
    # custom slot to save the current image
    def mySave(self):
        filepath = os.path.join(
            QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.TempLocation),
            'zoomed_photo.jpg')
        print(f'Saving: {filepath}')
        try:
            self.plotCanvas.figure.savefig(filepath)
        except Exception as exception:
            QMessageBox.warning(
                self, 'Save Error', str(exception), QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Comment: How do I delete the left "save" button that is in the initial code?

Comment: @just_learning In `OrthoView.__init__`, add "Save" to the list of buttons that are hidden, like this: `if action.text() in ['Customize', 'Subplots', 'Save']:`.

Comment: Ok, I miss what to do when the `if` is true...